# django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: templates/index.html Error

Tags: python, django

I am making a Django authentication program but keeps on giving me this error.
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: templates/index.html Error.

PLS help me coz I have spent hours trying to solve this problem.

**Views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse 

def home(request):
    return render(request, "authentication/index.html")

def signin(request):
    return render(request, "authentication/signin.html")


def signout(request):
    pass
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('',views.home, name = "home"),
   path('signin',views.signin, name = "signin"),
   path('signout',views.signout, name = "signout"),
]
```

**Settings**

```
"""
Django settings for gfg project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '-tqa6(3cnb_f@3u(56)mu9z%d2c548xypd-@%6i&60@)mxbs$k'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'gfg.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ["templates"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'gfg.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

authentication is my app folder while gfg is my start project.

Comment: Can you provide a filetree that contains the template?

Comment: You haven't installed app in `settings.py` file .... you are using render function but you haven't imported render function ... also update file path so that it will be easy to debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what i can see in your code. you have to create a folder "templates" in the root of your project directory. you also have to create an "authentication" folder in the templates folder and place index.html in the authentication folder. it will work.